# Highcharts dynamic datalabel positioning

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

could I set y to percentage value?

```
plotOptions: { 
            gauge: { 
                dataLabels: { 
                    format: '123 456 789,666',
                    y: 100
                } 
            }
        },
```

I have jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/o0gdupjt/ i want to this string '123 456 789,666' will be updated dynamically (when i resize chart) and be displaying on the gauge not under. Nice if i can do this with DotNetHighcharts Library.

Comment: In case when you hardcode datalabel (by format) how it should be updated and which value should be printed ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't describe problem precisely, when i change width of page  datalabel goes under chart. I am using this chart in small div as a widget and it's looks bad.

Comment: Now all is right, but let me know how it should be printed, smaller font or other soluton, because there is no enough space, physically.

Comment: It should have a calculated proportionally position from the center of gauge, but you're right it's not bad now :)